# How to install version 3.7 of puppet on Debian Stretch?

Tags: linux, debian, puppet

I am trying to install puppet 3.7.2 on my server.

On all my nodes, I have the following:

```
apt-cache policy puppet
puppet:
Installed: 3.7.2-4+deb8u1
Candidate: 3.7.2-4+deb8u1
Version table:
    4.8.2-5~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
*** 3.7.2-4+deb8u1 0
       500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    3.7.2-4 0
       500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

On my new server, however, if I try to install this specific version, the following happens:

```
apt-get install puppet=3.7.2-4+deb8u1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.7.2-4+deb8u1' for 'puppet' was not found
```

Also:

```
apt-cache policy puppet
puppet:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.2-5
  Version table:
     4.8.2-5 500
        500 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

I am not very versed in Linux, how can I install this specific version?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't be installing Puppet 3.7. It is EOL long ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Matt that you shouldn't use puppet 3.7 as it is EOL long time ago.
However, if you really must, you can install the Wheezy Backports, by adding the line below to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

`deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main`

With this, you will be able to install the package.